# Convert a Promise to an async function

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm pretty new to javascript and am trying to convert the code below to an async function. As I understand it an async function always returns a Promise.

```js
// working code
export const getUser = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      if (user) resolve(user)
      else reject('Unauthorized')
    })(req, res)
  })
```

This Promise is being used with the `await` keyword:

```js
const user = await getUser(req, res)
```

My attempts thus far always return a "Function" and not a resolved or rejected Promise:

```js
// failing code
export const getUser = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) =>
  async () => {
      return await passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) throw err
      if (user) return user
      else throw 'Unauthorized'
    })(req, res)
  }
```

Thank you for pointing out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: If `passport.authenticate` doesn't return a Promise, then you can't. `async` functions are syntactic sugar around promises; if there is no promise, you can't use that syntax.

Comment: `passport.authenticate` is indeed a normal function. But it calls a callback. And I was hopen it was possible to wrap that in an `async` function. So I don't have to use the `new Promise` syntax.

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to work but try await promisify(passport.authenticate)(...YOUR_PARAMS) and import {promisify} = require('util');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a function instead of a Promise because `new Promise` creates a promise **immediately**, but `async () => {}` only creates a promise when it is **called**.

… but that is the least of your problems.

`async` functions are tools to manage existing promises. They are not freely interchangeable with the promise constructor.

`passport.authenticate` doesn’t return a promise, so you can’t use `async` to manage it.

Comment: Thank you, that first sentence about when it's created cleared a lot up. So in a way it can be done but then with an IIFE. Which makes it less readable. Sticking with the defaults then.

Comment: An IIFE wouldn't help: You still wouldn't be able to control if the promise would be resolved or rejected from the callback function you pass to `passport.authenticate`

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, you can not use it like this here. However, in case you would need to write an async function, it would look like this.

```
export const getUser = async (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
   return await functionThatReturnsAPromise()
}
```